# Constrained least squares

Tags: r, lm

I am fitting a simple regression in R on gas usage per capita. The regression formulas looks like:

```
gas_b <- lm(log(gasq_pop) ~ log(gasp) + log(pcincome) + log(pn) +
            log(pd) + log(ps) + log(years), 
            data=gas)
summary(gas_b)
```

I want to include a linear constraint that the beta coefficients of `log(pn)+log(pd)+log(ps)=1` (sum to one).  Is there a simple way of implementing this (possibly in the `lm` function) in R without having to use `constrOptim()` function?

Comment: What are pn, pd and ps? Are they dummy variables?

Comment: No they are 
#PD = Price index for durables component of total consumption
#PN = Price index for nondurables component of total consumption
#PS = Price indes for services component of total consumption

Microeconomic theory might predict that the three elasticities on nondurables price, logPN, durables price, logPD and services price, logPS, should sum to one.

Answer (score 8):

Modify your regression as follows:

```
gas_b <- lm(log(gasq_pop) - log(ps) ~ log(gasp) + log(pcincome) +
  I(log(pn)-log(ps)) + I(log(pd)-log(ps)) + log(years), data=gas) 
summary(gas_b)
```

If `b=coef(gas_b)`, then the relevant coefficients are

```
log(pn): b[4]
log(pd): b[5]
log(ps): 1 - b[4] - b[5]
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, ran that and it worked like a charm.  However, I couldn't find in the R manual, what the "I"  in front of  I(log(pn)-log(ps)) and I(log(pd)-log(ps)) stands for?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: I stands for identity. see help(I).