# Linear model with Constraints

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and I have a following problem:

I have a simple 2-factor linear model:

```
Rate~factor1 + factor2 //factor1 has 8 categorical values, factor2 has 6 categories;
model1 <- lm(Rate~factor1+factor2, data=myData)
```

And want to put constraints SUM of factor1 coefficients = 0, the same for factor2.

None of the manuals gives any clue how to do this.

I found a link to similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1551554) but it is different and I couldn't figure out how to modify it...

Comment: This question was also asked the stats exchange site: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/

Comment: @csgillespie: thanks for the link.  @Vytautas: please do not cross-post.

Comment: Do you know how to specify a positivity constraint on the fit? How to do the fit so that the final function is always positive independently from the arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's described in chapter 6 of MASS (Modern Applied Statistics with S).  Use the `contrasts` arg of `lm` (take a look at `?contr.sum` and `?model.matrix.default` for examples).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it - it did not make the sum of coefficients = 0, but did minimize it (now is 0.2 for 1 factor and 0.08 for the other)

Comment: Is there a way to force ==0 condition ?

Comment: My answer is the way to force it.  If the sums are 0.2 for `factor1` and 0.08 for `factor2`, then the value for the last level of `factor1` is -0.2 and the value for the last level of `factor2` is -0.08.  Notice that your regression output is missing a factor level... This is also stated in the link contained in the answer you accepted on stats.stackexchange.com...